# temporary change touchpad settings from application WIN10

Tags: c++, windows, settings, touchpad

In my application I'm trying to temporary turn off
TwoFingerTapEnabled & TapsEnabled for the touchpad.
ProcMon confirms the regular windows GUI settings write the 2 registries within
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad

reading and writing the registries is no problem but to directly apply the new settings does not seem to get me anywhere.

so far I tried sending WM_SETTINGCHANGE messages, like

```
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\PrecisionTouchPad\\TapsEnabled"), 0, 1000, &res);
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT("TapsEnabled"), 0, 1000, &res);
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT("Environment"), 0, 1000, &res); //?
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)"Environment", SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, &res);
```

in these cases SendMessageTimeout always returns a non-zero value.

restarting the device(s) with PnpUtil

restarting the service hidserv

disabling and enabling in device manager.

but nothing seems to work

Trying to look in the [Settings Management Infrastructure (SMI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_smi/)
as an alternative option to change settings, but cant figure out how, or see any examples using SMI.

while trying things out I had settings GUI and regedit closed.
the Settings GUI can change the settings directly (with a small delay).